# C program to compute estimated root via Newtons Method

Tags: c, computer-science, newtons-method

I have the following code

```
/*
    KENDALL WEIHE
    CS321 HW2 PROBLEM 3
    PURPOSE: COMPUTE THE 5TH STEP OF NEWTONS METHOD TO ESTIMATE THE ROOT OF A FUNCTION
    INTPUTS: INITIAL X0 = 1.5
    OUTPUTS: ESTIMATED ROOT AFTER 5 ITERATIONS
*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //f(x) = -x^3 + x^2 + x + 1
    //f'(x) = -3x^2 + 2x + 1
    //l(x) = f'(x)(x - x0) + f(x)
    //l(x) = (-3x0^2 + 2x0 + 1)(x - x0) + (-x0^3 + x0^2 + x0 + 1)
    //where x0 = x sub 0 || x nought 
    //substitute x0, solve for x
    //x becomes new x0, iterate 5 times
    //solving for the root we find
        //0 = l(x) 
        //x = [4x0^3 + x0^2 - 1]/[3x0^2 + 2x0 + 1]
    int i;
    int x0 = 1.5;
    int x;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        x = (4*x0^3 + x0^2 - 1)/(3*x0^2 + 2*x0 + 1);
        x0 = x;
    }
    printf("%d",x);
}
```

It's a fairly straight forward program as long as you understand newtons method (slide 16) http://www.cs.uky.edu/~jzhang/CS321/lecture2.pdf

I'm getting 0 as the output. Any ideas?

**SOLUTION**

I made a stupid mistake thinking the `^` operator was for exponents (Homer Simpson *dough*) => the correct operator is by using the `pow()` function

Comment: `int x0 = 1.5;` do you mean `double`? And use `pow()` instead of `^` (`^` means bitwise xor in C)

Answer (score 4):

```
 int x0 = 1.5;   // you want double or float I think . prefer double
```

And in this expression -

```
 x = (4*x0^3 + x0^2 - 1)/(3*x0^2 + 2*x0 + 1);
```

This `^` does not mean what you think (or what you **expect** from it) . It is Binary XOR Operator in C.

Either write it manually like this -
  `x0`'s cube **->** `x0*x0*x0` .

Or use function [`pow`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_pow.htm) from header `<math.h>` .

**1.** declare `x0` and `x` as `double`.

**2.** calculate `x0`'s cube as

```
pow(x,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace all `int` with `double`. An `int` will truncate to integral values.
2. Rewrite `x0 ^ 3` to `x0 * x0 * x0` etc. (I prefer to not use `pow` for small integral powers, but handcode the multiplication). `^` in c is the XOR operator, **not** exponentiation.
3. Rewrite `printf("%d",x);` to `printf("%f",x);` once you've changed the *type* of `x`. If you don't do this then your program behaviour will be *undefined*.

Answer (score 1):

The `^` is binary `XOR` Operator in C.

For power calculation you can use [`pow()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/). But before use include `math.h`